# SSRS Date Parameter auto postback

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

I have created .rdl file with two date parameter. The report is working fine in local. But I am facing some difficulties after I integrated the rdl file into ASP.NET MVC application.

The problem is Date Parameter performs postback once I select the date. So I need to wait for some time to go with another parameter and  The performance of report is good  when  test it in local and Database.

Please share me if you have any solution.

Thanks.

Jay

Comment: See here http://sweechingho.blogspot.com/2011/06/prevent-ssrs-parameter-auto-postback.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried this one, but I was not able to get soln. The page is still refreshed once I select the date parameter.